# How to pass a global value in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I am building an angularjs based web app. I have included the ajax loader in the header. I have implemented bootstrap modals for login and signup. Each modal have its own controller. I didn't able to get ajax loader on and off values in the header. I want to implement some kind of Global value, which can be accessed throughout the ng-app scope.

Comment: whats an ajax loader?

Comment: Means I am displaying a loader animation during ajax call.

Comment: why would you do that outside of angular then? Angular's http service is promise-based, which means that you can turn the animation on before http request and turn it off after the request is resolved

Comment: I have included the loader animation div in header inside ng-app scope. And I am turning on animation just before $.http and on success, hiding it. Its working fine on normal pages. But in case of modal, I am getting the values inside modal scope but not in header.

Comment: Oh ok, in that case the $rootScope advice is solid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using **$rootScope** you can achieve this :

set global variable in mainwindow :

```
function MyMainWindow($scope, $rootScope) {
$rootScope.name = 'Root Variable'; }
```

modal Window read global variable :

```
function MyModalWindow($scope, $rootScope) {
$scope.name2 = $rootScope.name; }
```

call root folder using {{name2}}

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a value to $rootScope, or you can make your value a property of an AngularJS factory/service.

Answer (score 0):

You can add values to the $rootScope if you deed to with the following:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .run(function($rootScope) {
        $rootScope.key = val;
});
```

But you should avoid using global variables as much as possible. Sometimes you need to use them but other times it is a symptom that your app could be built a different, better way. For this instance, you might create a directive that is applied to the header.